# WhatsApp Business API - Edit Template

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a POST request to edit a template message of WhatsApp:

```
POST /{whatsapp_template_id}   
{
  "name": "my_template",
  "language": "en_US",
  "category": "transactional",
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "BODY",
      "text": "whatsapp buddy?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Receiving  `(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no edit template API, as per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates#edit-a-message-template) it will Available from September 7, 2022.